# Isometric City Building Game

Tags: java, game, graphics, libgdx

I have recently been working on my first game with an isometric perspective. For those who don't know, an isometric perspective is a pseudo 3D view created from 2D tiles.  I am working off of this tutorial about [isometric graphics](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-isometric-worlds-a-primer-for-game-developers--gamedev-6511).

I believe my approach is fairly clean and efficient.  I have tried to do things in an object oriented way.  For some of the math involved, I am relying on the code found in the tutorial linked above. I will include this code for completeness, but it is not really my code.

**Edit:** I changed the rendering to load all of the textures into a `Map` and then create one of each type of `IsoTile` out of those textures at game start. When the `IsoTile` is instantiated, a texture is passed into it by the libGDX game. The `IsoTile` splits the texture into the appropriate number of `TextureRegion`s that are all the same size. After that, the world map of `IsoTile`s is created. During rendering, the game checks whether or not the integer in the world data matches the type of the `IsoTile` in the world map, and if not then it changes that `IsoTile` to the appropriate type.  Then the renderer renders this world map each cycle.  For each `IsoTile` its array of `TextureRegions` is iterated over and drawn to the screen.

One benefit of doing things this way is that I can flip a switch and disable rendering beyond the initial `TextureRegion` in the array, and thereby clip the texture such that you can see the tiles behind it easily. I could also apply a different alpha value to these `TextureRegion`s instead to make them see through.

I should mention that I am already familiar with how to use `Screen` objects in order to separate the rendering logic into a `MainMenu` and `GameScene`, etc.  This is why the camera, batch, and textures are made public by the libGDX `Game` class. Eventually the different `Screen` objects will have their own `render()` and `draw()` methods and will need access to the loaded resources.

**IsoTile.java**

```
public class IsoTile {

    private int unitHeight;
    private int tileType;
    public List<TextureRegion> textures = new ArrayList<TextureRegion>();

    public IsoTile(Texture texture, int tileType, int unitHeight) {
        this.tileType = tileType;
        this.unitHeight = unitHeight;
        this.textures = this.splitTextureIntoRegions(texture);
    }

    public int getTileType() {
        return this.tileType;
    }

    private List<TextureRegion> splitTextureIntoRegions(Texture texture) {
        TextureRegion textureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture);
        List<TextureRegion> textures = new ArrayList<TextureRegion>();
        if (texture.getHeight() > this.unitHeight) {
            TextureRegion[][] textureMatrix = textureRegion.split(texture.getWidth(), this.unitHeight);
            for (int i = textureMatrix.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                TextureRegion[] textureArray = textureMatrix[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < textureArray.length; j++) {                             
                    TextureRegion region = textureArray[j];
                    textures.add(region);
                }
            }           
        } else {
            textures.add(textureRegion);
        }
        return textures;
    }
}
```

**IsoTileType.java**

```
public enum IsoTileType {

    GROUND(0, "ground02.png"),
    HOUSE01(1, "house02.png"),
    SCRAPER01(2, "scraper03.png"),
    LIGHTCOM(3, "lightCommercial02.png"),
    MEDCOM(4, "mediumCommercial02.png"),
    HIGHCOM(5, "highCommercial02.png"),
    LIGHTRES(6, "lightResidential02.png"),
    MEDRES(7, "mediumResidential02.png"),
    HIGHRES(8, "highResidential02.png"),
    LIGHTIND(9, "lightIndustrial02.png"),
    MEDIND(10, "mediumIndustrial02.png"),
    HIGHIND(11, "highIndustrial02.png");

    private int id;
    private String fileName;

    private IsoTileType(int id, String fileName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public int id() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String fileName() {
        return this.fileName;
    }
}
```

**IsoWorldGame.java**

```
public class IsoWorldGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    public static float STAGE_WIDTH;
    public static float STAGE_HEIGHT;

    public CameraPanner cameraPanner;
    public PinchZoomer pinchZoomer;
    public InputMultiplexer inputHandler = new InputMultiplexer();

    public OrthographicCamera camera;
    public Stage stage;
    public SpriteBatch batch;

    private int defaultHeight;
    private boolean clippingEnabled = false;

    private List<ArrayList<IsoTile>> worldTiles;
    private Map<Integer, Texture> allTextures;
    private Map<Integer, IsoTile> allTiles;

    private MainGame mainGame;
    private double currentTime = 0;
    private double timeSinceLastUpdate = 0;
    private double timeBetweenUpdates = 1000;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        //configure screen size
        if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Desktop ||
            Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.WebGL) {
            IsoWorldGame.STAGE_WIDTH = 1400; //Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            IsoWorldGame.STAGE_HEIGHT = 900; //Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        } else {
            //good for phone shape
            IsoWorldGame.STAGE_WIDTH = 480; //Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            IsoWorldGame.STAGE_HEIGHT = 800; //Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        }

        mainGame = new MainGame();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(STAGE_WIDTH, STAGE_HEIGHT);
        camera.setToOrtho(false, STAGE_WIDTH, STAGE_HEIGHT);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(STAGE_WIDTH, STAGE_HEIGHT, camera), batch);

        //controls
        inputHandler.addProcessor(stage);
        this.cameraPanner = new CameraPanner(camera);
        this.cameraPanner.setEnabled(true);
        this.pinchZoomer = new PinchZoomer(camera);
        this.pinchZoomer.setEnabled(true);
        inputHandler.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(this.cameraPanner));
        inputHandler.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(this.pinchZoomer));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputHandler);

        this.allTextures = this.loadTextures();

        Texture defaultTile = this.allTextures.get(0);
        this.defaultHeight = defaultTile.getHeight();

        this.allTiles = this.createTileSet();

        this.worldTiles = this.createWorldTiles(this.mainGame.world.levelData);
    }
    private Map<Integer, Texture> loadTextures() {
        Map<Integer, Texture> textures =  new HashMap<Integer, Texture>();
        for (IsoTileType type : IsoTileType.values()) {
            Texture texture = new Texture(type.fileName());
            textures.put(type.id(), texture);
        }
        return textures;
    }
    private Map<Integer, IsoTile> createTileSet() {
        Map<Integer, IsoTile> tileSet =  new HashMap<Integer, IsoTile>();
        for (IsoTileType type : IsoTileType.values()) {
            tileSet.put(type.id(), new IsoTile(this.allTextures.get(type.id()), type.id(), this.defaultHeight));
        }
        return tileSet;
    }
    private List<ArrayList<IsoTile>> createWorldTiles(int[][] worldData) {
        List<ArrayList<IsoTile>> isoTiles = new ArrayList<ArrayList<IsoTile>>();
        for (int i = this.mainGame.world.levelData.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            ArrayList<IsoTile> row = new ArrayList<IsoTile>();
            for (int j = this.mainGame.world.levelData[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                int tileType = this.mainGame.world.levelData[i][j];
                row.add(this.allTiles.get(tileType));
            }
            isoTiles.add(row);
        }
        return isoTiles;
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));
        stage.draw();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        super.render();

        this.updateWorld(this.worldTiles);

        int scaleReducer = 12;
        float gapReducer = 0.78f; //smaller is a smaller gap
        for (int i = this.worldTiles.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            List<IsoTile> row = this.worldTiles.get(i);
            for (int j = row.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                IsoTile tile = row.get(j);
                IsoPoint point = new IsoPoint((int)(i * this.defaultHeight * gapReducer / scaleReducer), 
                                              (int)(j * this.defaultHeight * gapReducer / scaleReducer));
                IsoPoint convertedPoint = IsoHelper.twoDToIso(point);

                int count = 0;
                for (int h = 0; h < tile.textures.size(); h++) {

                    //clipping for visiblity of tiles behind tall tiles
                    if (this.clippingEnabled) {
                        if (count > 0) {
                            break;
                        } else {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }

                    TextureRegion textureRegion = tile.textures.get(h);
                    batch.draw(textureRegion, 
                               convertedPoint.x, 
                               convertedPoint.y + h * this.defaultHeight / scaleReducer, 
                               textureRegion.getRegionWidth() / scaleReducer, 
                               textureRegion.getRegionHeight() / scaleReducer);;
                }
            }
        }

        this.batch.end();

        double newTime = TimeUtils.millis();
        double timeElapsed = newTime - this.currentTime;
        this.currentTime = newTime;
        this.timeSinceLastUpdate += timeElapsed;

        if (this.timeSinceLastUpdate > this.timeBetweenUpdates) {
            this.timeSinceLastUpdate = 0;
            this.mainGame.world.updateWorld();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Depends on the world size not changing
     */
    private void updateWorld(List<ArrayList<IsoTile>> world) {
        for (int i = this.mainGame.world.levelData.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            ArrayList<IsoTile> row = world.get(i);
            for (int j = this.mainGame.world.levelData[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                int tileType = this.mainGame.world.levelData[i][j];
                IsoTile currentTile = row.get(j);
                if (currentTile.getTileType() != tileType) {
                    row.set(j, this.allTiles.get(tileType));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the helper class that I ported from the original ActionScript.  Other than porting it to Java and changing some variable names I have not made any other changes.

**IsoHelper.java**

```
public class IsoHelper {
    /**
     * convert an isometric point to 2D
     * */
    public static IsoPoint isoTo2D (IsoPoint point) {
        //gx=(2*isoy+isox)/2;
        //gy=(2*isoy-isox)/2
        IsoPoint newPoint = new IsoPoint(0, 0);
        newPoint.x=(2*point.y+point.x)/2;
        newPoint.y=(2*point.y-point.x)/2;
        return(newPoint);
    }
    /**
     * convert a 2d point to isometric
     * */
    public static IsoPoint twoDToIso (IsoPoint point) {
        //gx=(isox-isoxy;
        //gy=(isoy+isox)/2
        IsoPoint newPoint = new IsoPoint(0, 0);
        newPoint.x=point.x-point.y;
        newPoint.y=(point.x+point.y)/2;
        return(newPoint);
    }

    /**
     * convert a 2d point to specific tile row/column
     * */
    public static IsoPoint getTileCoordinates(IsoPoint point, int tileHeight) {
        IsoPoint newPoint = new IsoPoint(0, 0);
        newPoint.x=(int)Math.floor(point.x/tileHeight);
        newPoint.y=(int)Math.floor(point.y/tileHeight);
        return newPoint;
    }

    /**
     * convert specific tile row/column to 2d point
     * */
    public static IsoPoint get2dFromTileCoordinates(IsoPoint point, int tileHeight) {
        IsoPoint newPoint = new IsoPoint(0, 0);
        newPoint.x=point.x*tileHeight;
        newPoint.y=point.y*tileHeight;
        return(newPoint);
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the game without the clipping enabled:

[image: city_no_clipping]

Here is an image with clipping enabled:

[image: city_with_clipping]

**World.java**

```
public class World {

    private int tileTypes = 11;

    public int[][] levelData = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1},
                                {2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                                {1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 10,1},
                                {1, 0, 0, 7, 7, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                                {1, 1, 9, 7, 7, 7, 1, 0, 1},
                                {1, 1,11, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
                                {1, 8, 5, 3, 1, 6, 6, 0, 1},
                                {1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 6, 6, 0, 1},
                                {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}};

    public void updateWorld() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.levelData.length; i++) {
            int[] row = this.levelData[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                int currentNumber = row[j];
                int nextNumber = currentNumber + 1;
                if (nextNumber > this.tileTypes) {
                    nextNumber = 0;
                }
                this.levelData[i][j] = nextNumber;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

The `World` object is really simple right now and will be more complicated later.  The `updateWorld()` is simply for fun/testing so that I can generate this output:

[image]

As always, any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the `IsoPoint` class something that you have made or is that something you import from LibGDX?

Comment: It is my class. It's just a simple point class with x and y integer members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using a double for-loop, I'd stay away from `i` and `j` names for the variables. I think `x` and `y` is better, even if we're dealing with Isometric coordinates, perhaps you can come up with something even better.

---

There is one main concern I have in your code, and that is this part in the render method:

```
IsoPoint point = new IsoPoint((int)(i * this.defaultHeight * gapReducer / scaleReducer), 
                              (int)(j * this.defaultHeight * gapReducer / scaleReducer));
IsoPoint convertedPoint = IsoHelper.twoDToIso(point);
```

This creates new objects in each and every call to `render`. The `render` method is called, as you know, continuously. This is causes a lot of extra work for the device and puts a lot of extra work on the garbage collector. **Avoid creating objects in a continuous loop.** There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092887/avoiding-object-allocations-in-ondraw-staticlayout) [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472529/object-allocation-during-draw-layout) [about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377240/avoid-object-allocations-during-draw-layout-operations-preallocate-and-reuse-in).

In this case, you could actually perform the operations using **only one** `IsoPoint` object that you re-use every time.

```
// Outside render method
private IsoPoint point = new IsoPoint();

// In render method
for (int i = this.worldTiles.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    List<IsoTile> row = this.worldTiles.get(i);
    for (int j = row.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        IsoTile tile = row.get(j);
        point.set((int)(i * this.defaultHeight * gapReducer / scaleReducer), 
                  (int)(j * this.defaultHeight * gapReducer / scaleReducer));
        point.convertTwoDToIso();

        int count = 0;
        for (int h = 0; h < tile.textures.size(); h++) {
            ...

            TextureRegion textureRegion = tile.textures.get(h);
            batch.draw(textureRegion, 
                       point.x, 
                       point.y + h * this.defaultHeight / scaleReducer, 
                       textureRegion.getRegionWidth() / scaleReducer, 
                       textureRegion.getRegionHeight() / scaleReducer);;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this way, the `IsoPoint` object `point` essentially becomes a storage place for two variables, `x` and `y` and now you continuously mutate those variables, instead of creating a bunch of new variables every time.

*Alternatively,* you could have each `IsoTile` store a permanent reference to the `IsoPoint` object that can be used for the calculation.

Either way, **Avoid creating objects in a continuous loop**